# ceph-libs package can be removed?

Tags: package, archlinux

I'm wondering if the aur/ceph-libs can be removed as it looks like it's not required by anyone :

```
pacman -Qi ceph-libs
Name            : ceph-libs
Version         : 16.2.7-1
Description     : Distributed, fault-tolerant storage platform delivering object, block, and file system
Architecture    : x86_64
URL             : https://ceph.com/
Licenses        : GPL
Groups          : None
Provides        : ceph-libs=16.2.7-1
Depends On      : boost-libs  curl  glibc  keyutils  libutil-linux  bzip2  lz4  nss  oath-toolkit  python  snappy  systemd-libs  fmt  cryptsetup  lua  librdkafka  python-prettytable  python-yaml  python-setuptools
Optional Deps   : None
Required By     : None
Optional For    : None
Conflicts With  : ceph-libs-bin
Replaces        : None
Installed Size  : 73.35 MiB
Packager        : Unknown Packager
Build Date      : Tue 11 Oct 2022 08:12:31 PM CEST
Install Date    : Wed 12 Oct 2022 08:28:54 AM CEST
Install Reason  : Installed as a dependency for another package
Install Script  : No
Validated By    : None
```

Note : if this package is somehow needed, looks like pre-built binaries exist here for faster installation:
https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ceph-libs-bin

Any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

Only you can know if you need it. You could remove it and install it again if you do need it.

If you ran into the 30 hour build issue on the AUR package, here is some more info: https://archlinux.org/todo/removal-of-ceph-from/